# JS Tweenlite onCompleteParams sending null

Tags: javascript, gsap

doing a looped tween in Javascript runs just twice and then stops. in the debugger i can see that a Null value is sent after the 2nd time.

Any ideas how to fix this, or is it a bug with the Greensock library?

```
 TweenLite.to(box, 2, {left:Math.random() * 600,onComplete:completeHandler, onCompleteParams:box});


function completeHandler(obj) {
if (obj)
  TweenLite.to(obj, 2, {left:Math.random() * 600,onComplete:completeHandler, onCompleteParams:obj});
}
```

Comment: `onCompleteParams` requires an `array`. I would assume (by the naming of your variables), that you've got that wrong.

Comment: no, because it works the first 2 times.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle or the like.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.. what does the `box` variable reference. And like @ahern commented above .. `onCompeleteParams` requires an Array. View the GreenSock Docs: http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/TweenLite.html

Answer (score 4):

```
TweenLite.to(box, 2, {left:Math.random() * 600,onComplete:completeHandler, onCompleteParams:[box]});


function completeHandler(obj) {
if (obj)
  TweenLite.to(obj, 2, {left:Math.random() * 600,onComplete:completeHandler, onCompleteParams:obj});
}
```

*/
You just have to pass parameters in array .
*/